# selecting column a.qty-b.qty only if b.qty exists else return a.qty

Tags: sqlite

i have two tables with two colums (a, b) in first and (c,d) in second.
i want the select statement to give a-c where b=d;  which works fine but i need the value of a-c to give if the corresponding b=d doesn't exist, i hope i have been able to explain

```
table 1:
(a,b)
(10,1)
(10,2)
(10,3)

table 2: (c,d)
(5,1)
(5,2)
```

so, select (a-c),b from tables where b=d returns

```
(a-c,b)
(5,1)
(5,2)
```

where i want

```
(a-c,b)
(5,1)
(5,2)
(10,3)
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: i want the select statement to give a-c where b=d; which works fine but i need the value of a-c to give the value of 'a' if the corresponding b=d doesn't exist, i hope i have been able to explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT t1.a-COALESCE(t2.c,0), t1.b
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
  ON t1.b = t2.d
```